# Trim() doesn't work

Tags: c#

Why does my fileName equals with something like "29.06.2014 17:04:23.pdf" ?

```
string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string fileName = dateTime.Trim() + ".pdf";
```

I don't understand why there is a space between date and time. Even

```
string fileName = Datetime.Now.Date.ToString() + Datetime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ".pdf";
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `trim()` only removes the whitespace at the beginning and end.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to see what `Trim()` actually does?

Comment: From [documentation of `String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx); Removes all **leading and trailing** white-space characters from the current String object

Comment: then TrimEnd() and TrimStart() what does?

Comment: @George02 They take off the given character(s) at the start or the end of the string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [String.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string dateTimeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString();

string fileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf"
    dateTimeStr.Replace(" ", String.Empty));
```

Because [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method deals only with whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the string